# Openerp validation not work on common users

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I have wrote some validation rules in on-change function in one of my modules and it's perfectly working over **admin account** but not over in any other user accounts. Please help me with this.

***function***

```
def onchange_sub_nominee(self, cr, uid,ids,employee_id,date_to, date_from,sub_nominee,half_day,half_day_status):
    #Employees data
    DATETIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    from_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from, DATETIME_FORMAT).date()
    to_dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to, DATETIME_FORMAT).date()

    sub_name=self.pool.get('hr.employee').browse(cr, uid, sub_nominee).name

    hol_obj=self.pool.get('hr.holidays')

    if employee_id==sub_nominee:
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_('Leave Denied: You can not be substitute to yourself '))

    #if date_from==date_to:
    hol_objs=hol_obj.search(cr, uid, [('employee_id','=',sub_nominee),('type','=','remove'),('state','not in',['draft','refuse'])])
    #nominees data
    if hol_objs:
        for a in hol_obj.browse(cr, uid, hol_objs):
                    sub_from_dt = a.date_to                                            
                    sub_to_dt=a.date_from
                    no_days=a.number_of_days_temp
                    sub_half_day=a.half_day
                    sub_half_day_sts=a.half_day_status

                    f_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(sub_from_dt, DATETIME_FORMAT).date()
                    t_dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(sub_to_dt, DATETIME_FORMAT).date()

                    if ((from_dt==to_dt)and(to_dt==f_dt==t_dt)and (half_day != True)):

                         raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_(' %s already on leave on %s . Please nominate another person ')%(sub_name,from_dt))

                    if ((from_dt==to_dt)and(to_dt==f_dt==t_dt)and (half_day == True) and (half_day_status==sub_half_day_sts) ):
                            raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_(' %s already on leave on %s , %s. Please nominate another person ')%(sub_name,from_dt,sub_half_day_sts))

                    if ((from_dt!=to_dt)) and(no_days<=2): 

                        while from_dt <= to_dt :                         
                              new_con=self.search(cr, uid, [('date_from', '<=', date_to), ('date_to', '>=', date_from), ('employee_id', '=', sub_nominee)])
                              if new_con:
                                  raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_(' %s has/have already on leave(s) on that period  . Please nominate another person')%(sub_name))
                              from_dt = from_dt + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

                    if ((f_dt!=t_dt)):                                                         
                        while t_dt <= f_dt:                                
                            if (from_dt==t_dt)or(to_dt==t_dt):
                                raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_(' %s has/have already on leave(s) on that period  . Please nominate another person')%(sub_name))

                            t_dt=t_dt+datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    return True
```

I think that there is not any wrong with the function. But can not understand why it doesn't work with any user account apart from admin

Comment: It's look like record rule issue , you need to check access rites & record rule.

Comment: Is just validate functions also applied over record rules ? If so please kindly explain because so far I thought that those validation functions are invoke in generally over every user